# Excel plug in for TFS 2012 without installing VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, excel, tfs

Is it possible to have the "team" plug-in for Excel (MS TFS 2012) without having to install Visual Studio 2012?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Excel integration comes as part of [Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656). Installing it installs all the TFS integration bits on your machine (and allows you to install things like the Shell extension power tools). It does also install small Visual Studio shell but one that doesn't include any of the programming tools etc.

You only need a license to access your Team Foundation Server to install Team Explorer (i.e. a TFS CAL) - no additional Visual Studio license required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is pretty much what I've found as well but I was hoping that I was missing something. :)

Comment: Sadly not.  Remember also that to get updates for these tools you actually have to install the Visual Studio Updates (i.e. currently Visual Studio Update 2). This is a bit of a pain I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing [Visual Studio 2012 express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) web or some other version, if Team menu is not showing up yet in excel then try installing TFS 2012 Express also try installing [Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30656)